# Issue with Pact Verify Provider Maven Plugin

Tags: java, pact

Despite having the Pact file correctly placed in the folder, I am getting this exception:

```
You must specify the pactfile to execute for consumer.
```

Please help!

My POM.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-actuator-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-reporting-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
                <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.8</version>
                <configuration>

                        <serviceProviders>
                            <!-- You can define as many as you need, but each must have a unique 
                                name -->
                            <serviceProvider>
                                <name>DrivePOC1</name>
                                <!-- All the provider properties are optional, and have sensible 
                                    defaults (shown below) -->
                                <host>localhost</host>
                                <port>9000</port>
                                <path>/</path>
                                <consumers>
                                    <consumer>
                                        <name>ExpensePOC1</name>
                                        <pactFile>Consumer_080517/target/pacts/ExtensePOC-DrivePOC.json</pactFile>
                                    </consumer>
                                </consumers>

                        </serviceProviders>
                    </serviceProviders>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Maven Pact Verify Goal Screenshot :[image]

The error I get is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
   au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11:3.3.8:verify (default-cli) 
   on project gs-actuator-service: Execution default-cli of goal 
   au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11:3.3.8:verify failed:
   You must specify the pactfile to execute for consumer 'consumer1' 
   (use <pactFile> or <pactUrl>) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: The error message you have there doesn't seem to correspond to the XML you've posted. You have `ExpensePOC1` as the consumer name in the post, but are missing the file for `consumer1` in the error message.  Could you double check you've posted the right file?

Comment: Also, in the posted XML, you're using `DrivePOC` for the provider name in the pact file, but `DrivePOC1` for the name in the POM.